# Why the scale parameters of this object is 2000 times bigger and there is almost no difference between the two?

Tags: transforms, scale, dimensions

I have those two objects that have dimensions that are pretty much the same.
Normally the bigger rectangle should be much more bigger because the scale is 2000 times bigger.

Here is the .blend file : https://www.mediafire.com/file/rjkkx9eby442xm9/support_disques_dur.blend/file

[image: big rectangle]
[image: small rectangle]

Comment: scale doesn't say anything really except the factor from local to global space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the original scale of the object (when you added it) was relative to its first size (scale of an object is relative to its own original size, unlike dimensions).
To reset that scale just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and click on apply scale, then you will see the object scale is [ 1, 1, 1 ] (unit scale). I hope that helps.